# Ckeditor is not working fine in simple blog in models.py django

Tags: ckeditor

my model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField #(this field imported)

# Create your models here.
class Blog_post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.RichTextField(blank=True) #(this field in body is not defined)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and CKEditor is installed I followed a tutorial same as but in my case whenever I enter make migration it says the name RichTextField is not defined and I don't know how to fix it any kind of help will be apriciated

Comment: I already fixed it I was using ``` models.RichTextField()``` error is throw because RichTextField is not defined in models you should only use   ```tex=RichTextField()``` it was a typo

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it I was using  `models.RichTextField()` error is throw because RichTextField is not defined in models you should only use tex=RichTextField() it was a typo – baibars313 just now